# Is the any way to make an selective protection using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Hi
Is there a way to protect a folder and its contents using .htaccess file but only from external access?
Meaning: files inside the server can access the folder but if some one tries to access it directly it prompts for an user and password.

I'm using AuthType Basic already. But when an external file tries to access the image inside the protected folder, there emerges the problem.

To clarify (at least try to), what I have is one folder with many, many images and I don't want them to be accessed but I want my php scripts to have access outside the folder. Like 
/index.php
/images/ -> same level of index.php
/admin/photos/ -> index.php can access the files inside this folder without restriction. something like the files has its own user and password.

Comment: "files" cannot access anything by themselves. Perhaps you mean "processes"?

Comment: "Files inside the server" (assuming you mean what @thkala says) won't respect `.htaccess`, so, technically, simply using `.htaccess` will accomplish what you want, right?

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things you can do but I think you might want to clarify your question. I *think* what you're asking is how you protect certain files from web access but still allow your scripts (like a PHP script) to be able to access the data.

If that's the case then you simply need to put your data files outside of the `DocumentRoot`. Apache will only load files that it is allowed to access but PHP, or other scripting languages can access any file anywhere (as long as the user the process executes as has the appropriate permissions)

If you really want user/password access to certain files from the web:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My super secret folder"
AuthUserFile "/path/to/some/user_file"
require valid-user
```

That will restrict outside access but will not restrict any access from scripts or people/programs on the server itself.